# Which granular permission is required to write to a list's root folder property bag?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, custom-list, folder

In order to write to a list's root folder's property bag, does a user need "Manage Lists" permission?

Or would they be able to do it with just "Add Items" / "Edit Items"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user should have "Manage Lists" permission.